# Fetch pending entries with GraphQL

Tags: entries, graphql, pending

I'm setting up Craft to be used headlessly with a mobile app, and content will be created several days before it is published. I want app admins to be able to see upcoming/pending entries. Is there a way to fetch all entries, not just currently published ones? When I do basic queries with the GraphQL api explorer I only see entries that are past their post date, but I'm a GraphQL newbie, so maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `live` and `pending` entries, you would need to pass `status` to your query with the values you want ([docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#status)).

```
query yourQuery {
  entries(section: "yourSectionHandle", status: ["live", "pending"]) {
    title
  }
}
```

Or if you want to use variables:

```
query yourQuery($section: [String], $status: [String]) {
  entries(section: $section, status: $status) {
    title
  }
}

# query variables:
{
  "section": "yourSectionHandle",
  "status": ["live", "pending"]
}
```

If you want all entries, (`disabled` and `expired` included) you can use `status:null`.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much!